# Managed Extensions for C++ in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, managed-extensions

Is anyone aware if /clr:oldsyntax (Managed Extensions for C++) will be removed from Visual Studio 2012?

The messages have been warning it will be removed since 2008 and I'm concerned the time may be close to up.

Comment: That's not how it works.  It is deprecated indefinitely, until supporting it becomes too painful.  Then it gets yanked.  Lots of turmoil in the compiler because of C++11 and C++/CXX, there's another easy 9 months before anybody knows for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed Extensions for C++ syntax is deprecated but as for the [VS 2012 RC, still here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As of Visual Studio 2015 the Managed Extensions for C++ has been removed.

[msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(v=vs.140).aspx)

> Visual C++ no longer supports the /clr:oldsyntax option. This option was deprecated in Visual Studio 2005.